# How to load and blit image python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, blit

I am trying to use the

```
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename
```

to load an image and then blit it on screen, but it isn't working out.
I created a Rect button so that when I click it it would open the dialogue box to load 
an image. After loading it I want it to blit but it is not working.(error).
Here is my code:

```
if loadrect.collidepoint(mx,my) and mb[0]==1:
            filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=Formats,title="Choose an image to open")
            if filename!= None:
                screen.blit(filename,(203,44))
```

How would I correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pygame, you have to load the image first, just passing its filename is not enough (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

```
if loadrect.collidepoint(mx,my) and mb[0]==1:
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=Formats,title="Choose an image to open")
    if filename!= None:
        surface = pygame.image.load(filename)
        screen.blit(surface,(203,44))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about loading the image.

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert your image to a pygame object. For example using:

```
sprite = pygame.image.load(filename)
screen.blit(sprite, (203,44))
```